# File written to ZIP file available only during runtime [Java]

Tags: java, path, filesystems, java-7, nio

I am having issue with writting a binary file to simple ZIP archive using Java 7's `FileSystem` and `Files` API.

The problem occur while performing write operation, which throws no exception at all, the file is not written to the ZIP archive, but is available in runtime (`Files.exists(backup)` returns true and it's possible to read the file using `Files.readAllBytes(backup)` ).

When program is closed and relaunched, the file is not available anymore.

**Snippet**

This method should create backup of any path, no matter who is the FileSystem provider, 'fails' just on paths inside ZIP archives.

```
/**
 * Creates backup of path provided by 'file' parameter.
 *
 * @param file input file requiring backup creation
 * @return backup file
 * @throws java.io.IOException thrown in case of unsuccessful backup attempt
 */
public static Path createBackup(Path file) throws IOException {

    FileSystem fileSystem = file.getFileSystem();
    Path backup = fileSystem.getPath(file.toString() + ".BAK");

    return Files.write(backup, Files.readAllBytes(file));

}

public static void main(String... args) {
   try {

      Path f = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get("a.zip"), null).getPath("file.bin");

      Path backup = createBackup(f);

      System.out.println(Files.exists(backup)); // prints "true"
      System.out.println(new String(Files.readAllBytes(backup))); // prints its bytes
      System.out.println(backup.toString()); // prints "file.bin.BAK"
   } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.err.println(ex);
   }

}
```

But the file does not physically exists in the ZIP.

**EDIT**:
I've managed to make it work, but there is a problem. Code below closes the file system, but writes properly. There is need to "refresh"/"reopen" filesystem somehow.

```
public static Path createBackup(Path file) throws IOException {

   try(FileSystem fileSystem = file.getFileSystem()) {

      Path backup = fileSystem.getPath(file.toString() + ".BAK");
      return Files.write(backup, Files.readAllBytes(file));

   }
}
```

When original method is keept and file system is closed manually after everything is done, it removes the zip file and keeps something like `zipfstmp***.tmp`and throws:

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: zipfstmp2666831581340533856.tmp -> a.zip
```

When the tmp file is renamed to "a.zip", its a valid modified archive.

Comment: try showing the correct compile-able `main` code - you are saying that *throws no exception at all* but the code in its current state does not compile due to many uncaught exceptions

Comment: Edited. Just surrounded the main code with try-catch.

Comment: Have you tried catching a general exception to see if it throws an unexpected type of exception?  Obviously do not do this permanently.

Comment: @AndrewS - The operations throw just IOException, otherwise it would fall on uncaught exception, but the build completed successfully somehow.

Comment: Ok then catch both and see.

Comment: @AndrewS same result, when I attempt to write backup again (in the same runtime) it throws FileAlreadyExistsException. If you create a simple zip with one file in it you can check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should close using the try-with-resource statement within the caller, which created the file system. There is no need to deal with file systems in the `createBackup` method at all.

```
public static Path createBackup(Path file) throws IOException {
    Path backup = file.resolveSibling(file.getFileName().toString()+".BAK");
    return Files.copy(file, backup, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
public static void main(String... args) {
    try(FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get("a.zip"), null)) {
       Path f = fs.getPath("file.bin");
       Path backup = createBackup(f);

       System.out.println(Files.exists(backup)); // prints "true"
       System.out.println(new String(Files.readAllBytes(backup))); // prints its bytes
       System.out.println(backup.toString()); // prints "file.bin.BAK"
    } catch (IOException ex) {
       System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is how I did it in second example, but the problem is that I need to work with the original file (object instance) after backup was created (outside main), so it throws ClosedFileSystemException.

Comment: Then, the caller (outside main) should be responsible for creating and closing the file system. Otherwise, there’s no other solution than closing and reopening…

Comment: It works, but man now I know why people are beginning to dislike Java.. That try line is rather compact and a little obtuse (though not your fault).

Comment: @Holger this has bitten me once again (I stopped loosing count of how many times I fail with `FileSystem`). Suppose such a case: a method that reads a certain `URI` using `FileSystem` and return a `Path`; later some callers of the method use this path to do something. Since I am using try with resource when accessing `FileSystem` - I almost always get `ClosedException` and I keep forgetting I must return the `FileSystem` to the callers also, so that they close it. This rant is actually more of a question: would there be a cleaner way to handle this? ... thank you

Comment: @Eugene when you return a `Path`, you’re also returning a `FileSystem`, as every `Path` has a `getFileSystem()` method. The actual problem is to tell whether that file system has be closed after use or not. There’s no way around returning an instance of a dedicated type which knows whether the file system has to be closed. It may have a `Path getPath()` method and implement `Closeable`, but do nothing on `close()` if this particular file system should not be closed (like the default file system). Then, the caller doesn’t need to think about it and may always use a `try(…) { … }`.

Comment: @Holger thank you for the comment, it makes a lot more sense now and of course I will re-write this a bit since you made me understand where my mistake was

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example where all the logic is in the main method.

The key to solving this is in using a URI to state explicitly what kind of File System provider to use. You may wonder why jar and not zip. In Java a jar files are in fact zip files but with a different file extension. So java can use the same mechanisms to access zip files.

I tried this with binary files and text files and it seems to work on my Win 10 machine. Just change the source directory of the zip file (///e:/a.zip) to point to the location of your zip file. For me the file.bin.BAK was written to the root of eclipse project directory (you might want to change that also for deployment).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {

            //Create URI to define the source as a Zip file.
            //I've used jar because this is essentially a zip file.
            Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
            env.put("create", "true"); 
            URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:///e:/a.zip");

            try{

                //Build paths to source file in zip  and externally.
                Path pathInZipfile = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env).getPath("/file.bin");  
                Path extPath  = Paths.get("file.bin.BAK");


                //If file does not exist create it.
                if (! Files.exists(extPath))
                    Files.createFile(extPath);


                //Copy the files over.
                 Files.copy( pathInZipfile, extPath,
                            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING ); 

            }//end try
            catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }//enc catch

    }//end main
}//end class
```